# Gremlin: Unable to add edges to graph using console

Tags: gremlin

I have created a graph using the following command and I am not able to a find a way in which I could add edges to it.

```
g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()
g.addV('A1').addV('A2').addV('A3').addV('B3').
```

I have tried few variants of the following command to add edge.

```
g.V('A2').addEdge('pre',V('A1'))
No signature of method: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.DefaultGraphTraversal.addEdge() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.DefaultGraphTraversal) values: [pre, [GraphStep(vertex,[A1])]]
```

Comment: Version: Apache TinkerPop 3.2.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't mention what version you're using, so I'll be referring to Apache TinkerPop 3.2.3. Here is a link to the documentation for the [add edge step](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.2.3/reference/#addedge-step) `addE()`.

When you created your vertices, [add vertex step](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.2.3/reference/#addvertex-step) `addV()` takes the vertex label as the parameter, not an id. Vertex labels aren't usually unique, so you're better off using the id.

```
gremlin> Gremlin.version()
==>3.2.3
gremlin> g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
gremlin> g.addV('A1').addV('A2').addV('A3').addV('B3')
==>v[3]
gremlin> g.V().valueMap(true)
==>[id:0,label:A1]
==>[id:1,label:A2]
==>[id:2,label:A3]
==>[id:3,label:B3]
gremlin> g.V(1L).addE('pre').to(g.V(0L))
==>e[4][1-pre->0]
```

Comment: Can you also tell if we can add an edge using a vertex property, eg. name? I didn't understand the following line in the documentation.
`.hasLabel('software').addE('createdBy').to('a') //(2)`

Comment: @atulshgl the above line says bring all vertices that have label ```software``` and connect them with vertex ```a``` (which was declared with ```as("a")``` earlier in the traversal) using an edge of label ```createdBy```

Comment: In last line, what is `1L`, what does L represents here?